# Defining Matrices with argument in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix A=[1-x, 2;1 3-x].  How do I define this in Mathematica so I can do things like

SchurDecomposition(A[1])

and

f[x_]:= maximum eigenvalue of A[x_];  then plot f for x in [-1,1].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just proceed the same way as with any other function definition:

```
A[x_]:={{1-x,2},{1,3-x}}
```

Then:

```
SchurDecomposition[A[1.]]
```

and

```
Plot[Max[Eigenvalues[A[x]]],{x,-1,1}]
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Actually, Mathematica returns numerical eigenvalues sorted by absolute value - so you could replace `Max` with `First`.